# Foundation data-interchange doesn't show image

Tags: image, zurb-foundation, webp

So, I have an challenge with webp images on my site. As you can see below it doesn't show the image but instead renders the image code.

[image]

When I use a jpg file it's works like a charm. My code is below. The image should be shown as 'cover' on a div. The framework I use is Foundation 5. I know it is outdated but I'm working on a new site and for now don't want to upgrade but thought serve webp images instead of jpg's could be a quick fix to limit the bandwith on Cloudinary, where the images are hosted.

```
<div class="small-6 medium-4 large-4 columns" style="background-size: cover;" data-interchange="[/-/media/Global/NoImage.jpg, (default)], [https://res.cloudinary.com/Company/image/upload/w_195%2Ch_195%2Cc_fill/f_auto/v1625496788/MainFolder/T/3554/t2scdia2gtw8vswjh575.webp, (small)], [https://res.cloudinary.com/woningnet/image/upload/w_300%2Ch_195%2Cc_fill/f_auto/v1625496788/MainFolder/T/3554/t2scdia2gtw8vswjh575.webp, (medium)], [https://res.cloudinary.com/woningnet/image/upload/if_ar_lt_1%3A1/h_600/if_else%2Cw_800/if_end/c_fill/f_auto/v1625496788/WRB/T/3554/t2scdia2gtw8vswjh575.webp, (large)]" data-uuid="interchange-qqqAg0">
```

I've been searching online but so far no solution, most things I've found where explanations why you should webp. Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be using Foundation 6.7.4 and found the solution by making a change to the foundation.js or min.js file depending on which one you are calling and adding |webp to the end of the path match.

(path.match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|tiff)
to
(path.match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|tiff|webp)

Edit/Update: I Found a copy 5.5.1  on an older site the foundation.js or min.js

```
      if (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)([?#].*)?/i.test(path)) {
        $(el).css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');
        el.data('interchange-last-path', path);
        return trigger(path);
      }
```

Should be able to add |webp

```
      if (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|webp)([?#].*)?/i.test(path)) {
        $(el).css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');
        el.data('interchange-last-path', path);
        return trigger(path);
      }
```